# How to get IP address of the calling client of a SOAP Web Services (Apache Axis 1.4) without context

Tags: java, soap, axis, soap-client

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.
I am trying to get the ip address of a soap web service client that calls a web services that doesn't have a context.

I am using Jdk 1.8, Soap Web Services (Apache Axis 1.4).

I have the following code and it works if there is a context called "test1" http://localhost:8080/test1/services/TestService

In my context.xml I could get ip address of client if there is a context called "test1":

If my context.xml don't have context called "test1 than it will not work:

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!